# Shopware 6 override twig block plugin

Tags: plugins, twig, overriding, shopware

I installed some plugin. I want to override the block named  "neti_store_locator_detail_config" in the file *vendor/store.shopware.com/netinextstorelocator/src/Resources/views/storefront/store_locator/detail.twig*

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/base.html.twig' %}

{% block base_content %}
    {% block neti_store_locator_detail %}
        <div class="neti-next-store-locator-detail">
        {% block neti_store_locator_detail_config %}
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ page.config|json_encode|escape }}" ref="config">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ page.store|json_encode|escape }}" ref="store">
        {% endblock %}
        ...
```

So I created plugin by command *bin/console plugin:create SwagStoreLocator* and create file *custom/plugins/SwagStoreLocator/src/Resources/views/storefront/store_locator/detail.twig*

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/base.html.twig' %}

{% block neti_store_locator_detail_config %}
    <div>Not working :(</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Then I installed and turned on plugin in the admin panel. I typed *bin/console cache:clear* and *bin/console theme:compile*. Unfortunately there is not errors, no override … How can I edit only twig from plugin. I don't want to do it in the vendor folder, because it's not allowed to commit such folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know how annoying it can become when overwrites silently just won't work. I think there are two issues here. When overwriting */netinextstorelocator/src/Resources/views/storefront/store_locator/detail.twig*, you need to adjust the *sw_extends* command in the twig-template:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/store_locator/detail.twig' %}

{% block neti_store_locator_detail_config %}
    <div>Not working :(</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This may already work when the folder-structure and extends are set correctly. If not, you have to set the "overwrite-hierarchy" in a config file called "theme.json". Please have a look at this documentation here: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/themes/theme-configuration

```
{
  ...
  "views": [
     "@Storefront",
     "@NetiNextStoreLocator",
     "@SwagStoreLocator",
     "@Plugins"
  ],
  ...
}
```

In the example above I already inserted both of your plugins. The templates will be rendered in the defined order: Shopware > NetiStoreLocator > your plugin > all other plugins